# Change dynamically the view of every item of a ListView

Tags: android, listview, children

I want to change the visibility of an image of each item of a `ListView` when clicking on an external button (I mean which is not part of the `ListView`).

So I need to access all the children views of a `ListView`. Then I did a loop like this one :

```
for (int i = 0...
{
     View child_view = list_view.getChildAt(i);
     ...
}
```

The problem is that, this way, I can only access the currently visible children, and I need to access the view of **every** child of the `ListView`.

How can I do such a thing?

Comment: From where you are loading images is it from the internet or from the drawable resources..?

Comment: Have you tried that......

Comment: If you have time, consider watching this video: [Google I/O 2010 - The world of ListView](http://youtu.be/wDBM6wVEO70). It's about an hour, and is worth the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by:

- changing all the visible children with this : [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6740089/android-getting-a-count-of-the-visible-children-in-a-listview)
- changing the non-visible children in the function getView of the adapter because, and it's important, getView refreshes on scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

Solution is simple

in Your Adapter class take a int array like this

```
int visibilities[]={ImageView.VISIBLE,ImageView.GONE,ImageView.INVISIBLE};
```

if you are setting the images from the Drawable Resources than You probably pass the ids to the ArrayList items
something like this

```
CountriesList.add(new Country("India",R.drawable.india));
```

Than create another variable in the Country class(Your Bean class(Getter setter class))
and set it type int
something like this

```
class Country{
String name;
int flag;
int visibility;
}
```

pass the visibility like this while adding elements to your list

```
 CountriesList.add(new Country("India",R.drawable.india,1));
```

And in your getView() method of the Adapter you will probably set the resource like this

```
holder.image.setImageResource(country.getFlag());
```

also add this line

```
holder.image.setVisibility(visibilities[country.getVisibility]);
```

In order to explain this I have added country example.. I Have used the same trick in my  previous app for the list... and it worked like charm.. I hope this will help you.